# How to cause data abort and prefectch abort in arm v7

Tags: c, exception, arm

I would like to create a data abort and pre-fetch abort to test whether the exception handlers for the same  are getting called properly or not. As per my understanding that dereferencing a NULL pointer can cause data abort. But I am not getting how to create a pre-fetch abort for testing. I am working on armv7a. I am not using any OS, working on the boot code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both of these are bus faults, jumping into unknown code is going to result in an undefined instruction not prefetch abort.  I would focus on unaigned accesses do an ldr with bit 1 set and do a bx with bit 1 set (but bit 0 not set) would be where I start.  If those dont work it might not be possible with a test fixture inside the chip.

There may be portions of the address space that dont respond, those should simply hang the processor, but you might get lucky and the memory controller returns a fault.

if you have parity or ecc in your system those would be the best way, assuming you have a way to inject an error into those memories to force a parity or ecc fault (also assuming that the memory controller, etc for that design (little to no logic that is relevant to your question is part of the ARM processor) returns a fault on a parity or ecc error).

cortex-m might fault on some address spaces as they to some extent dictate where you are supposed to go.

If one of the newer cores you can use the mmus protection and I dont know if that returns a data/prefetch fault or not, setup the mmu such that some space is at a different access level than the code you are going to hit it with and see what fault you get.

EDIT

Have to look for an armv7 but on an armv6 (pi 1 for example) if I enable alignment checking in the control register, and do an ldr of say address 0x1001 which is an alignment fault then it gives me a data abort.

save a line of code and use address 0x01

```
mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0
orr r0,#2
mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0
mov r0,#0x1
ldr r0,[r0]
```

jumping into an invalid instruction causes an undefined not a prefetch abort, the memory system has to assert the abort, so you can use the mmu for this most likely,

undefined exception

```
.globl TEST
TEST:
    .word 0xFFFFFFFF
    bx lr
```

easiest way to make a prefetch abort (as stated in the ARM ARM).

```
.globl TEST
TEST:
    bkpt
```

Comment: ahh sorry you did say armv7...maybe I have a raspberry pi laying around...

Comment: an unaligned address, bx to 0x1002 did not cause a prefetch nor undefined got luckly and it tried to keep running, normally it would eventually hit an undefined, thought it might trigger a prefetch but it didnt.

Comment: reading the armv7 ARM it also says  BKPT can be used, unless in HYP mode then you get a Hyp Trap instead of a prefetch.  Basically just read the arm docs.  Understanding that these aborts you are after come from the bus controller be it inside the core (mmu for example) or the chip vendor logic, data itself with a valid access will not cause an abort, but could cause an undefined at best if it is a fetch.  So you have to position yourself ideally to cause the bus logic to abort, and that means see the vendor docs usually.  BKPT and unaligned being exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

For a data abort you can just attempt to read an unmapped or non-readable memory region. For example try reading/writing a NULL pointer. 
For prefetch abort just try jumping to a random address in some unmapped, non-readable or non-executable region (do you have MMU enabled at this stage?):

```
mov r0, #0xFFFFFFFF   ; Some address that is satisfying the above
push r0   ; push it to the stack
pop  pc   ; jump to that address
```

Note, that just jumping to a random address might result in an Undefined abort instead, as it might be executable but contain an unknown instruction.

Comment: not containing executable code is going to cause an undefined not prefetch abort.

Comment: @old_timer if the memory region is not executable, not readable  or not mapped it will cause prefetch. If it is containing an unknown instruction it will cause undefined

Comment: true, if you have the mmu set for that, but branching to some random address without "executable" code simply results in an undefined, unless those other things you said, so having valid code is not relevant.